# Reffrencing a control from view to ViewModel whitout Breaking The MVVM Pattern in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mvvm

I was wondering how to draw a line to a canvas that implements the MVVM Pattern when creating a WPF application, so I have in my view a text box, a button, and a canvas, and I want to enter the number of lines in the text box and when I click the button I want to draw the lines on the canvas.
The big question here is, can I add Children to a canvas in WPF without referencing the canvas control to my ViewModel (I heard that referencing a control to ViewModel break the MVVM pattern).

Comment: You need to create a property in the ViewModel that contains the observable collection.
The collection will contain elements with the usual properties that set the parameters of lines and / or other geoometric objects: position, size, color, etc аnything you need.
In XAML, you set the ItemsControl bound to this collection.
In the item template ItemTemplate, you specify how the collection item should be displayed.
Replace the ItemsPanel with Canvas.
In the style of the ItemContainerStyle, set the binding of the item's position in the Canvas

Comment: Does you really need to draw directly in canvas? Could you just create ordinal image then bind it to the Image conrol?

Comment: Mvvm is just a pattern. You use it because it's positives exceed it's negatives. In our map drawing app the view has a reference to it's viewmodel. Events are handled in the view, processing is done and a vm is added to an observablecollection in that viewmodel. I could have added a dependency property, bound something to that and acted in the viewmodel.